# Split the value of input to array of characters

Tags: javascript

I want to get the value of the input on click then split the returned value into an array of characters, that what i've already tried :

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var textonaut = {
    text: '',
    letters: []
  };
  textonaut.text = document.getElementById('textonaut-text').value;
  var go = document.getElementById('go-button');
  go.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    textonaut.letters = textonaut.text.split('');
    for(var i = 0; i < textonaut.letters.length; i++) {
      console.log(textonaut.letters[i]);
    };
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="textonaut-text" type="text"><button id="go-button">go</button>
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

Comment: at `textonaut.text` the textonaut variable is undefined, declare this variable globally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: Sorry you're sad and angry. Go read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `textonaut.text = document.getElementById('textonaut-text').value;` inside your `addEventListener` callback. Then it should work.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var textonaut = {
    text: '',
    letters: []
  };

  var go = document.getElementById('go-button');
  go.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    textonaut.text = document.getElementById('textonaut-text').value;
    textonaut.letters = textonaut.text.split('');
    for(var i = 0; i < textonaut.letters.length; i++) {
      console.log(textonaut.letters[i]);
    };
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="textonaut-text" type="text"><button id="go-button">go</button>
```

If you set the value of `textonaut.text` outside the callback, it will remain as `''` no matter what happens (this value is set when the JS file loads).

The callback function of the `addEventListener` is triggered at every `click` on the button. It means that at every `click`, the value `textonaut.text` is set at everything's inside your `input`.

Read [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) documentation for more information.

Comment: yes, this is the answer. but could you explain why it does not work the other way ?!

Comment: okay... Zakaria Acharki gave the answer, thanks to both of you !

Comment: You were setting the `textonaut.text` value only once, when `window.onload` event finished, by moving this asignment inside the `go` click event, you asign `textonaut.text` value to be whatever the input field text is each time `go` is clicked

Comment: @Timo explained

Answer (score 0):

You should get the input value after the click not before, so put the line :

```
textonaut.text = document.getElementById('textonaut-text').value;
```

Inside the callback.

**NOTE :** As written now in your OP the `document.getElementById('textonaut-text').value` will always return an empty string "".

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var textonaut = {
    text: '',
    letters: []
  };

  var go = document.getElementById('go-button');
  go.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    textonaut.text = document.getElementById('textonaut-text').value;
    textonaut.letters = textonaut.text.split('');
    for(var i = 0; i < textonaut.letters.length; i++) {
      console.log(textonaut.letters[i]);
    };
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="textonaut-text" type="text"><button id="go-button">go</button>
```